# Cascading stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The question is relatively simple.

Is possible to call a procedure in MySQL, into another?

Example:

There are two procedures created: proc1 and proc2

Within the proc1, I call proc 2.
Thus:

```
BEGIN

IF ( CALL ConsultConsoleAvailableTime(`StartTime`, `PlusTime` ) IS NULL ) THEN
    SELECT 'error';
END IF;

END;
```

Is it possible? How? Did not work here not. :D

Edit1:

1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE sistemajogosxbox.ConsultConsoleAvailableTime; expected 3, got 2

Edit2:

1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

And now?

Comment: For `Edit1` it seems your procedure `ConsultConsoleAvailableTime` expects three parameters, to which you only supplied two: `StartTime` and `PlusTime`

Comment: They have been satisfied. I do not know why this message.

Comment: I made a little mistake here. I'm repairing.
I believe you are right and your response.

Comment: I think 'LIMIT 1' can solve my problem. Right?

Comment: It's likely. Get only one row and one column and see what happens..

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate one way to use a stored procedure within another:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE setOutputParameter (
    OUT OutputParameter VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN

    SELECT 'output' INTO OutputParameter;

END//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE useOutputParameter ()
BEGIN
    CALL setOutputParameter(@tmpOutputParameter);

    IF @tmpOutputParameter = 'output' 
        THEN SELECT 'string: output was returned' AS res;
    END IF;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Procedure `setOutputParameter` sets a value to its `out` parameter, and then that value is created a placeholder for in procedure `setOutputParameter` (and into variable: `@tmpOutputParameter` which is then checked in the `IF..THEN..` statement.

Again, this may not be the simplest example and might even be overkill for procedures (use functions as a possible alternative), and there are other ways to return values to be used within a stored procedure that aims to utilize the output of one stored procedure in it.

[edit] Based on post comment:

An `INOUT` or `OUT` parameter (only available in stored procedures, and not functions) inside a stored procedure allows the caller of the stored procedure via `CALL storedprocedurename..` command to pass a user defined variable to the `out` parameter's position of the called procedure--in which that same procedure runs and passes a value to it. After the called procedure executes, the `out` value, passed into the user-defined variable becomes available. In the example above, the `out` parameter `OutputParameter` in stored procedure `setOutputParameter` will require a variable to be passed to it upon being called, because the stored procedure `setOutputParameter` will pass a value to it. So, in effect, once the code inside stored procedure `useOutputParameter` calls if via `CALL setOutputParameter(@tmpOutputParameter);`, the variable it passed to act as an out parameter: `@tmpOutputParameter` will now contain the string value `output` which the rest of the code within procedure `useOutputParameter` can use...

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: An output parameter in MySQL stored procedures is a parameter to which you pass a value from within the stored procedure and then is accessible after the same stored procedure runs. In the case above.. wait, let me modify my post..

Answer (score -1):

You can call one stored procedure from another. I have done it before.

I think your example is dodgy because `proc2()` doesn't have a return value, like a function would. Perhaps you will need to make `proc2()` a function instead of a procedure.